# Android NDK cpu_features not found

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have an issue with `cpu_features` lib for Android NDK. I downloaded [lib](https://github.com/google/cpu_features) and copied it to my project directory. My `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.6)

add_subdirectory(cpu_features)

add_library(
    myLib
    SHARED
    app/src/main/cpp/test.cpp
)

link_libraries(myLib cpu_features)
```

My `test.cpp` file:

```
#include "test.h"
#include <cpu-features.h>
```

I have `10: fatal error: 'cpu-features.h' file not found` error. 
I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you have `ndk_compat` among your link libraries if you want to use the `cpu-features` drop-in replacement?

Comment: @Michael thanks, but please explain how to make it?

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd try would be `link_libraries(myLib cpu_features ndk_compat)`

Comment: @Michael unfortunately, the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `add_subdirectories` line is correct. For `link_libraries`, I got it working with this:

```
target_include_directories(myLib PRIVATE cpu_features/ndk_compat)

target_link_libraries(
        myLib
        cpu_features
        ndk_compat
        ${log-lib})
```

(the documentation on the github repo could be improved. If this works for you, maybe make a pull request to add this to the docs?)